# How to get touch event for uibutton outside of another uiwindow

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton, hittest

I have my firstVC in the main window and when a button is pressed I animate a second window from the bottom right hand corner that stops almost 3/4 way of the entire screen. Everything animates fine. The problem is I have a cancelButton (red X) on the outside of the second window and when I tap it nothing registers. I know it's outside of it's parent's bounds so I tried a `hitTest` but still nothing.

```
func setAnchorsForCancelButton() {

    secondWindow?.addSubview(self.cancelButton)

    cancelButton.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: secondWindow!.topAnchor, constant: -10).isActive = true

    cancelButton.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: secondWindow!.leadingAnchor, constant: 10).isActive = true
    // width and height are 35
}

func hitTest(_ point: CGPoint, with event: UIEvent?) -> UIView? {

    let translatedPoint = cancelButton.convert(point, from: secondWindow!.rootViewController!.view)

    if (cancelButton.bounds.contains(translatedPoint)) {
        return cancelButton.hitTest(translatedPoint, with: event)
    }
    return hitTest(point, with: event)
}
```

The Red X is a cancel button that is on the outside of the second window. It's not receiving the touch events

**How can I get it to receive the touch events while still outside of the second window?**

[image]

code that launches the Second UIWindow:

```
class SecondWindow: NSObject {

    lazy var cancelButton: UIButton = {
        // button created
    }()

    var secondWindow: UIWindow?
    let webViewVC = WebViewController() // instagram gets shown in here
    let navVC: UINavigationController?

    override init() {
        super.init()
        // some Notifications are in here
    }

    func animateFromBottom() {

        guard let keyWindow = UIApplication.shared.keyWindow else { return }

        let startingFrame = CGRect(x: keyWindow.frame.width - 10,
                                   y: keyWindow.frame.height - 10,
                                   width: 10,
                                   height: 10)

        let endingRect = CGRect(x: 0,
                                y: 150,
                                width: keyWindow.frame.width,
                                height: keyWindow.frame.height)

         let navVC = UINavigationController(rootViewController: webViewVC)

         secondWindow = UIWindow(frame: startingFrame)
         secondWindow?.windowLevel = UIWindow.Level.normal
         secondWindow?.rootViewController = navVC!
         secondWindow?.makeKey()
         secondWindow?.isHidden = false

         // a function with an animation animates the second window to the endingFrame

         setAnchorsForCancelButton()
    }

    func setAnchorsForCancelButton() {

        secondWindow?.addSubview(self.cancelButton)

        cancelButton.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: secondWindow!.topAnchor, constant: -10).isActive = true

        cancelButton.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: secondWindow!.leadingAnchor, constant: 10).isActive = true

        // width and height are 35
    }

    func hitTest(_ point: CGPoint, with event: UIEvent?) -> UIView? {

        let translatedPoint = cancelButton.convert(point, from: secondWindow!.rootViewController!.view)

        if (cancelButton.bounds.contains(translatedPoint)) {
            return cancelButton.hitTest(translatedPoint, with: event)
        }
        return hitTest(point, with: event)
    }
}
```

button from firstVC that launches the second window:

```
@obj func launchSecondWindow(_ sender: UIButton) {

    let secondWindow = SecondWindow()
    secondWidow.animateFromBottom()
}
```

Comment: Have you considered simply expanding the view that contains the cancel button? i.e. Constrain the cancel button to the top left, inside the view - then constrain the Instagram view below it. Then set the `backgroundColor` to `clear`.

Comment: @jake I found the answer, thanks for the suggestion :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer [here](http://khanlou.com/2018/09/hacking-hit-tests/) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16451902/4833705)

I subclassed UIWindow and did an override to the hitTest inside of there.

```
class AnotherWindow: UIWindow {

    override func hitTest(_ point: CGPoint, with event: UIEvent?) -> UIView? {

        for subview in subviews.reversed() {

            let convertedPoint = subview.convert(point, from: self)

            if let candidate = subview.hitTest(convertedPoint, with: event) {

                return candidate
            }
        }

        return self
    }
}
```

Then inside the SecondWindow class I used my subclass instead:

```
// this was what I originally used
var secondWindow: UIWindow?

// **This is what I'm using now**
var secondWindow: AnotherWindow?
```

Comment: Worked perfectly for me. `.convert` is really handy!